# Where can the default rule be matched?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex, diagnostic-tools

I have been slowly getting used to the whims of the flex lexer and, while it's pretty cool once (1) I have manage to get it to actually work and (2) I have learned just how it works,  I am not sure how to improve upon my grammar definition.

The grammar is medium-complex, so I would prefer not to paste it here. **I added it - see below**
But here are the build stats.

```bash
/usr/local/bin/flex -P -d -v 
classic.lpp:466: warning, -s option given but default rule can be matched
flex version 2.6.4 usage statistics:
  scanner options: -+dsvB8 -Cem -Pc
  314/2000 NFA states
  114/1000 DFA states (563 words)
  40 rules
  Compressed tables always back-up
  7/40 start conditions
  187 epsilon states, 127 double epsilon states
  26/100 character classes needed 322/500 words of storage, 0 reused
  1385 state/nextstate pairs created
  250/1135 unique/duplicate transitions
  123/1000 base-def entries created
  545/2000 (peak 748) nxt-chk entries created
  72/2500 (peak 333) template nxt-chk entries created
  220 empty table entries
  14 protos created
  9 templates created, 18 uses
  37/256 equivalence classes created
  8/256 meta-equivalence classes created
  2 (5 saved) hash collisions, 151 DFAs equal
  0 sets of reallocations needed
  1629 total table entries needed
```

Apart from the fact that I don't really know what the above means (except from things which are obvious like the number of rules and start conditions), what I don't know is how to get flex to tell me **where** the default rule can be matched.

Of course I can add a default rule 'catch'

But that means I have to find a means of triggering it.
Again, I can ruthlessly draw up a regex/match analysis and walk through it until I find what is missing - but is there no way that flex can tell me eg: "in start rule 3, the following characters are not being matched??

---

**minimal example of the grammar follows**

**flex version 2.6.4**

`/usr/local/bin/flex -P -d -v adv.lpp`

```
%option debug
%option noyywrap noinput nounput nodefault
%option noyymore
%option never-interactive
%option c++
%option stack
%option warn
%x parm brace bracket fatone literal injection

DELIMITER           ,
ALTDELIM                ⁏
BRACKET_IN          \(
BRACKET_OUT         \)
FAT_ONE_IN          ❪
FAT_ONE_OUT         ❫
LITERAL_IN          ⎣
BRACE_IN                ⎡
BRACE_OUT           ⎤
INJECT_SIGN         ⍟
I_OFFSET                \^*
I_NUMBER                [0-9]+
I_ITS                   [ijkn]
I_ITK                   [KN]
I_STACK             p([s]|[0-9]+)?
I_ITER              ([ijknKN]([+-][0-9]+)?([./]p?[0-9]+)?)
I_MORE              ([0-9]+("+"?))
MACRO_SIGN          ⌽
MACRO_NAME          [a-zA-Z_0-9]+
WHITESPACE          [\t\x0d\x0a]+
LCOMMENT                ⌽comment\(
LBCOMMENT           ⌽comment❪
LITERAL_OUT         ⎦
NOT_SPECIAL_1C      [^\t\x0d\x0a,\(\)\xe2]
NOT_LITERAL_OUT [^\xe2]|(\xe2(([^\x8e][^\0])|(\x8e[^\xa6])))
NOT_SPECIAL_3C      (\xe2[^\x81\x8c\x8d\x8e\x9d][^\0])|(\xe2\x81[^\x8f])|(\xe2\x8c[^\xbd])|(\xe2\x8d[^\x9f])|(\xe2\x8e[^\xa1\xa3\xa4\xa6])|(\xe2\x9d[^\xaa\xab])
JUST_TEXT           ({NOT_SPECIAL_1C}|{NOT_SPECIAL_3C})+

/**
   E2 81|8C|8D|8E|9D
 ❪ E2 9D AA √ FAT_ONE_IN
 ❫ E2 9D AB √ FAT_ONE_OUT
 ⁏ E2 81 8F √ ALTDELIM
 ⌽ E2 8C BD √ MACRO_SIGN
 ⍟ E2 8D 9F √ INJECT_SIGN
 ⎡ E2 8E A1 √ BRACE_IN
 ⎣ E2 8E A3 √ LITERAL_IN
 ⎤ E2 8E A4 √ BRACE_OUT
 ⎦ E2 8E A6 √ LITERAL_OUT
 **/

%%

<literal>{
    {LCOMMENT} {
        yy_push_state(parm);
        return( token::MACRO_IN );
    }
    
    {LBCOMMENT} {
        yy_push_state(parm);
        return( token::MACRO_IN );
    }
    
    {LITERAL_IN} {
        yy_push_state(literal);
    }
    
    {LITERAL_OUT} {
        yy_pop_state(); /**  Pop Literal **/
    }

    {NOT_LITERAL_OUT} {
        return( token::TEXT );
    }

    <<EOF>> {
        cerr << "Unexpected end of text before close literal";
        yy_pop_state();
    }
}

<bracket>{
    {BRACKET_OUT} {
        yy_pop_state();
        return( token::TEXT );
    }
}

<fatone>{
    {FAT_ONE_OUT} {
        yy_pop_state();
        return( token::TEXT );
    }
}

<parm,brace,bracket,fatone>{
    {INJECT_SIGN}({I_ITK}|{BRACKET_IN}{I_ITK}{BRACKET_OUT}) {
        return(token::INJECTION);
    }
}

<parm>{
    {DELIMITER} {
        return( token::PARM );
    }
    
    {ALTDELIM} {
        return( token::PARM );
    }
            
    {BRACE_OUT} {
        return( token::TEXT );
    }

    {BRACKET_OUT} {
        yy_pop_state(); /**  Pop Macro **/
        return( token::MACRO_OUT );
    }

    {FAT_ONE_OUT} {
        yy_pop_state(); /**  Pop Macro **/
        return( token::MACRO_OUT );
    }
    
    <<EOF>> {
        cerr << "Unexpected end of text before macro close.";
        yy_pop_state(); //pop parm!
    }
}

<brace>{
    
    {BRACE_OUT} {
        yy_pop_state();
    }

    {ALTDELIM} {
        return (token::PARMX);
    }

    <<EOF>> {
        cerr << "Unexpected end of text before close brace";
        yy_pop_state();
    }

}

<brace,bracket,fatone>{
    {DELIMITER} {
        return( token::TEXT );
    }
}


<INITIAL,parm,brace,bracket,fatone>{

    {LITERAL_IN} {
        yy_push_state(literal);
    }
    
    ({WHITESPACE}) {
        return( token::WSS );
    }
    
    {BRACE_IN} {
        yy_push_state(brace);
    }

    {MACRO_SIGN}{MACRO_NAME}{BRACKET_IN} {
        yy_push_state(parm);
        return( token::MACRO_IN);
    }
    
    {MACRO_SIGN}{MACRO_NAME}{FAT_ONE_IN} {
        yy_push_state(parm);
        return( token::MACRO_IN );
    }
    
    {MACRO_SIGN}{MACRO_NAME}{NOT_SPECIAL_1C} {
        return( token::TEXT );
    }

    {INJECT_SIGN}{I_OFFSET}({I_NUMBER}|{I_ITS}|({BRACKET_IN}{I_OFFSET}({I_STACK}|{I_ITER}|{I_MORE}){BRACKET_OUT})) {
        return(token::INJECTION);
    }
    
    {BRACKET_IN} {
        switch(YY_START) {
            case bracket: 
                case parm: {
                yy_push_state(bracket);
            } break;
            default: break;
        }
        return( token::TEXT );
    }

    {FAT_ONE_IN} {
        switch(YY_START) {
            case fatone:
            case parm: {
                yy_push_state(fatone);
            } break;
            default: break;
        }
        return( token::TEXT );
    }

    {JUST_TEXT} {
        return( token::TEXT );
    }
    
    {MACRO_SIGN}|{INJECT_SIGN}|{BRACKET_OUT}|{FAT_ONE_OUT}|{LITERAL_OUT} {
        return( token::TEXT );
    }
}

<INITIAL>{

    ({DELIMITER}|{BRACKET_OUT}|{FAT_ONE_OUT}|{BRACE_OUT}|{ALTDELIM}|{LITERAL_OUT}) {
        return(token::TEXT);
    }

}


%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, flex does not provide such a feature.

You can get a clue by trying every single character in every start condition until the scanner reports an error. That's just a few lines of code, using `yy_scan_buffer` to set up a single character input. [See code sample below].

Don't forget to try an EOF in every start condition; **a common cause of that warning is a start condition which doesn't handle EOF**. Sometimes that's a false positive, but a lot of times it's because you just didn't think about all the possible places an EOF might erroneously occur.

False positives can happen when a start condition is entered when you know what the next input character is, perhaps because the rule has trailing context or perhaps because you called `<yyless`. In such a case, you could reasonably fail to match a character sequence you know can't occur, but better style is probably to catch the sequence or EOF and interpose your own error message.

One particular case to look for is patterns for delimited tokens like strings or comments, where you haven't handled the possibility of a token missing its closing delimiter. In the case of strings, you also need to think about the possibility that the input ends in the middle of an escape sequence.

---

Using the code snippet below, I got the following report:

```
Failed to match 0XE2 in state INITIAL
Failed to match 0XE2 in state parm
Failed to match 0XE2 in state brace
Failed to match 0XE2 in state bracket
Failed to match 0XE2 in state fatone
Failed to match 0XE2 in state literal
```

Basically, you recognise a multibyte characters starting with 0xE2, and you recognise bytes other than 0xE2. But what about an input which hits EOF in the middle of the multibyte sequence starting 0xE2?  (Yes, it's an invalid input. But Flex doesn't know that.)

---

In case it's useful, here's a little code snippet which can be used to determine what character cannot be matched. In order to use this, you'll need to:

- Modify the list of states at the top of `main`
- Change all flex actions to `return 1;` (which can be mostly be done with a good text editor, by just injecting `return 1;` after the leading `{` of each action).
- Add catch-all rules at the end, in order to avoid triggering a fatal error when the unhandled character is tried:

  ```
  <*>.|\n          { return 2; }
  <INITIAL><<EOF>> { return 0; /* Needed so the next rule doesn't apply. */}
  <<EOF>>          { return 2; }
  ```
- Remove any reference to any symbol not defined in the Flex file (support functions, token definitions, etc.), or arrange for them to be defined.

All that done, you can just add the following in your flex file (it needs to be in the file in order to have access to the start condition definitions):

***NOTE**: This is the C version. If you remove all actions, then doing this test in C should be fine, but if you really want to use C++ then you'll need to make some minor adjustments.*

```c
int main(void) {
#define X(n) { n, #n }
  struct { int state; const char* name; } states[] = {
    X(INITIAL), X(parm), X(brace), X(bracket), X(fatone), X(literal),
    { -1, 0 }
  };
#undef X
  for (int i = 0; states[i].state >= 0; ++i) {
    int start = states[i].start;
    char buf[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    BEGIN(start);
    yy_scan_buffer(buf, 2);
    if (yylex() == 2)
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to match EOF in state %s\n",
              states[i].name);
    for (int ch = 0; ch < 256; ++ch) {
      buf[0] = ch;
      BEGIN(start);
      yy_scan_buffer(buf, 3);
      if (yylex() == 2)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to match 0X%02X in state %s\n",
                (unsigned)ch, states[i].name);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I think the problem is going to be on larger strings than single characters. I do indeed use EOF on all nested areas - (anywhere else EOF is legal - or are you saying I should catch EOF on INITIAL?) Oh, and I am not using 'yyless!'

Comment: What I am currently doing is posting a fake parse error on <*>(.|\n) - I just haven't seen any cases, despite thousands of test strings.

Comment: @konchog: the default rule only matches a single character. So if it is possible to trigger the default rule, you can trigger it with a single character. Knowing what that character is and which start condition cannot recognise it is a very good clue about where to look for the problem. (Unless the problem is at EOF in which case it is triggered by a 0-length input.)

Comment: If you do not paste an entire [mre], about all we can do is suggest how to diagnose the problem. This is how I diagnose such problems, and it's always worked for me. So it's the best advice I can give you.

Comment: if it helps I have followed your mention of a reproducible example as well as I am able.  There are a few things which may look 'weird' but mainly because I don't really know how to use lex to honour them - such as the fact that a macro that uses FAT_ONE_IN treats BRACKET_IN/BRACKET_OUT as TEXT (and vice versa), and similar with DELIMITER/ALT_DELIM.  I used logic in my scanner class to handle those things.

Comment: @konchog: That example is not a *reproducible example*. With a reproducible example, I should be able to reproduce the issue by copying the code snippets onto my machine and processing them with flex and gcc. That doesn't work here; your flex file is missing start condition definitions and token definitions. But it's enough to see that two of your start conditions (`bracket` and `fatone`) do not have EOF actions, contrary to what you said above ("I do indeed use EOF on all nested areas"). That's what Flex is complaining about.

Comment: Also, you might want to take a look at `yymore()`. You don't seem to be attempting to handle the token text in the code you pasted, but presumably you will want to do that, and `yymore` can help you build up the token when it requires combining several matches. Instead of `switch(YYSTATE)`, I'd use two different actions, one in `<INITIAL>` and the other for the rest of your states. (Check out the different between `%s` and `%x` states; that might be useful as well.)

Comment: @konchog, sorry, looking at this again, I do see the options and start condition declarations. I don't know how I missed them before. There you declare `injection` but it has no rules afaics; if it were entered, it would trigger a default rule, and flex cannot tell that it won't ever be entered.

Comment: Okay - well spotted with the injection!  That was a snippet before I realised I could match it without needing a start. I think you should be able use flex on it as is. I removed all the yylval (and related code) - because you asked for 'minimal reproducible' - and it seems that flex rules don't read that stuff.  Removing injection is great - but I am still seeing 'default rule can be matched'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245913/discussion-between-konchog-and-rici).

Comment: @konchog, ok got it, using the try-every-byte code snippet. See edited answer.

Comment: that was a brilliant idea.  I have implemented 0XE2 also.  But, for whatever reason, I still am seeing the same message! (Maybe my implementation is incorrect. I shall try out your cool code snippet!